# Memory leak when including Eureka form within table view

Tags: uitableview, eureka-forms

I have an application using Swift3 and Eureka Forms 2.0.0. I really love Eureka forms, but my app is leaking memory like crazy and I'm trying to pick it apart to see what's wrong. On the most basic level, I have a custom view controller that contains a table view (I have some other elements around the form that I need to control separately) that I want to tie into a Eureka form. However, even with the most basic possible case, I'm still seeing memory leaks. Here's the view controller I'm testing with:

```
class TestViewController: FormViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var formTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var mainText: UILabel!
    var titleString : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSLog("viewDidLoad")
        super.tableView = formTableView
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Just loading this and moving back and forth to another view results in the following leak report in Instruments:
[image: Leak screen shot]

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex